# warning: XMLReader::XML()

Tags: php, xml

I am reading a xml file with:

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->xml($myXml, NULL, LIBXML_NOWARNIG | LIBXML_NOERROR);
```

but in the same situation in any occasion show this warning on the line `$reader->xml($myXml, NULL, LIBXML_NOWARNING, LIBXML_NOERROR);`

```
warning: XMLReader::XML() [xmlreader.xml] Empty string supplied as input.
```

My question is, Why is showing the warning whether I have used the option `LIBXML_NOWARNIG.`

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the N in WARNING.

Also, it should be `new` not `nex` and the method signature of `XMLReader::url` is

```
bool XMLReader::xml ( string $source [, string $encoding [, int $options = 0 ]] )
```

which means you should call it

```
$reader->xml($myXml, NULL, LIBXML_NOWARNING|LIBXML_NOERROR);
```

However: both constants suppress **parsing errors** and passing an empty string to the method is not a parsing error but a logic error (you cannot parse an empty string) and thus, you cannot suppress it with them.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote bad the post but in the code if it is well written as LIBXML_WARNING

Comment: LOL Sorry soo much, nex is new in my code and thanks for response.